# Which is better if(condition == false) or If(!condition)

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, verification

I have always written my if statements like this when I want the negative condition to enter me into the if block.

**Example 1**

```
if(condition == false){}
```

However, we just hired a new senior on the team that insists we should refactor to

**Example 2**

```
if(!condition){}
```

and use that moving forward.

I find example #1 to be easier to reason especially when checking a nested property.

e.g. `if(person.name.middle.hasValue == false){}`

**Question**
What example is better to practice? or is there a better practice
than either example?

**Edit Scope** 
please limit answers to Negative conditions only. of course `if(condition == true){}` is worst than `if(condition){}` Because the `== true` is redundent for the true case but not the false case.

Comment: _"if(condition == false)"_ is obviously redundant and not necessary. Your senior is right about refactoring that. I also don't see how _nesting_ would make a difference here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not redundant. `condition == true` is redundant, but `== false` is the same as `!` - if you leave it out, you'll get wrong behaviour.

Comment: **Readability is King,**  which is why, like many things in software development, there's no *absolute* answer to this question.  As a general rule, however, any reasonably proficient C# developer will see `if(!person.name.middle.hasValue)` exactly for what it is.  If your find that hard to read, the better solution is to eliminate some of the dots, not tack `= false` onto the end of it.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Of course that's redundant regarding the `!` operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you mean a different word? You can't leave it out without changing the logic = it's not _redundant_.

Comment: @R.Schmitz Using explicit comparisons for boolean values is just redundant as I said. You can use just the value, or the negation in conditions. And yes, ***Readability is King***.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK i think i got you.

so maybe best is 
bool missingMiddleName = !person.name.middle.hasValue
if(missingMiddleName){}

???

Comment: @WizardHammer, no try `!person.hasMiddleName`? - introduce new method/property in Person class to encapsulate child members.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The word you are looking for is **equivalent** (which means that `!` and `== false` are interchangeable), not _redundant_ (which would mean that `condition == false` and `condition` are exactly the same)

Comment: @gnat  NO that question is different(though related).   while == true is always redundant. The same is not true for == false.  you can see flater and πάνταῥεῖ talking about this in the comments.

Comment: I don't find it important, however if you feel it is, here is another question that explicitly covers the matters you mentioned: [Why Use !boolean_variable Over boolean_variable == false](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/136908/31260) (these topics were generally very thoroughly covered in prior questions)

Comment: _we just hired a new senior_ - What is the reasoning this new senior provides to change a way you write `if` statements?

Comment: I'll just throw this in as a comment - you're all wrong wrong.  It should be `if (false == condition) ..` in order to avoid accidental assignments :D

Comment: @PeterM Ahh, the famous Yoda condition - but for bools!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question where you will get a direct answer, because both *work*. Most people will tell you it's a matter of taste. My personal opinion is: Don't lose sight of the end goal readability.

## My Favourite in a Perfect World

I prefer to write code that's "small and easy"; simple statements that are rather short. I prefer to use `!` in that code:

```
if(!IsReadable) SkipWord();
```

## Reality

At work we have a legacy project which - diplomatically said - is written in a way I personally don't prefer. Using `== false` makes it more readable. Imagine something like

```
if(word.IsReadable && sentence.HasSubclause && customer.HasAlreadyChosen == false
 || word.IsReadable == false && order.IsCompleted)
```

It can go on longer, but I'm gonna stop here. Don't pay much notice to how you could recombine the statements - the point is it's a lot of stuff, a lot of "noise" and it would be easier to accidentally ignore a tiny `!` in there.

Best would be to make the code overall more readable, but if a tool (resharper etc) can apply one of the styles throughout the codebase automatically, this is a way to prevent a whole bunch of bugs.

## In Summary

In my opinion: **Use `!` if your code is clean enough that it still stands out**.

And, probably obvious, but whichever one you end up using, never do `condition == true`.

And finally, mostly you'll work in a team and will have to use what the team agrees on, even if it *would* be an obviously worse decision.

Comment: `if (!IsReadable)` - If not is readable ;)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I  prefer `if (condition)` or `if (!condition)` to `if (condition == true)` or `if (condition == false)` or worse, `if (condition != true)`, because the latter three look like someone did not fully understand how if- (and other) conditions work.

Beginners often think that there must be some kind of comparison in an if-statement; however, this is not the case. What these kind of statements (`if`, `where` etc.) require, is a Boolean expression. I.e., an expression yielding either `true` or `false`. `expr == true` yields `true` when `expr` yields `true`, and `false` when `expr` yields `false`. So, the `== true` part doesn’t change the result of the expression. It's like writing `int y = x * 1;` instead of just `int y = x;`.

`condition == false` makes more sense than `condition == true`, but still smells like the latter.

Comment: "Looks like someone didn't fully understand" is not the reason you avoid it.

Comment: It's my reason. But of course, both variants are correct.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if using `if (!condition)` is any *less* readable than `if (condition == false)` then you have *other* problems with your conditional statement which you should work to resolve.

The `!` negation option also cuts down on visual clutter. Extra `== false` comparisons in the conditional increases the number of tokens you need to visually process, especially in more complex conditionals.

```
if (!isFeatureEnabled || (!isUserAuthorized && !isTestMode))
// --- rather than ---
if (isFeatureEnabled == false || (isUserAuthorized == false && isTestMode == false))

// ::: possible refactor :::
if (!isFeatureEnabled || !(isUserAuthorized || isTestMode))
// --- rather than ---
if (!isFeatureEnabled || ((isUserAuthorized || isTestMode) == false))

// ::: other possible refactor :::
boolean isUserAuthorizedOrTestMode = isUserAuthorized || isTestMode;
if (!isFeatureEnabled || !isUserAuthorizedOrTestMode)
// --- rather than ---
if (isFeatureEnabled == false || isUserAuthorizedOrTestMode == false)
```

For all these options I like those with `!` negation more. Yes, this example is pretty contrived but I could definitely see conditionals like this existing in real code.

Another note:
I read my conditionals from left to right with `!` read as "not", which in my opinion, combined with good variable names, makes the conditionals easier to verbalize and conceptualize than `== false` read as "is false".

Answer (score 0):

Another opinion - use right tool for the job - take one from both options.

For true condition `if (approved) { callMe }`
For false condition `if (approved == false) { callMe }`

The reason for using `approved == false` for is false condition only because it clearly stands out in comparing with true condition `if (approved)`.

But because the way we read code is different for different people and teams, use the way your team use. If you don't like team's approach - try to convince team to change their approach, if you can not change team's approach - change a team :)

Comment: Thank is not a thought that I had yet.  if (!approved) { callMe } would be easier to mistake  for if (approved) { callMe } then  (approved == false) { callMe }.